# how can I linear stretch an array to a bigger size one using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stretch

I would like to stretch an increasing numpy array linearly on a bigger sized array

[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] to something like: [1.25, 2.5, 3.75, 5, 6.25, 7.5, 8.75, 10]

but a solution that may receive a general increasing input and still stretch it linearly
say for example:

[ 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20, 20, 20] and stretch it linearly on array of size 20

Is there any existing numpy function or other simple way of doing that?

Edited:

I will try to make my question more understandable

I am trying to equalize an Image. 
As part of the process, I am using the histogram and cumulative histogram

when checking the cumulative histogram - my first gray level might not be 0, and my last gray level might not be MAX_VAL (255 in my case)
I would like to take the received values (some monotonically increasing array) , and to stretch them so my first gray level would be 0 , and my last would be MAX_VAL.

I was thinking about cropping the array by [first gray level: last gray level] and then to try and stretch it back to the original size (256 in my case) yet I don't seem to understand how to do that

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Probably what you want is loosely coupled with `numpy.linspace` but, trust me, your question is not clear... If you think you can improve your question, please [edit] it following the previous link.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
your_array = np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
streched_array = np.linspace(np.min(your_array),np.max(your_array),20)
```

Comment: I think, if the values in the original array are monotonically increasing like OP says, it suffices to use the first and last element as the lower and upper limits, rather than iterating over whole array twice in order to find min and max. But nice answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to use 'stretch' in two senses.  
1) to translate the values in an array to a given range.
2) To expand the array to a bigger array.

Version 1. a -> 0 to 255 with no change in size.

```
def translate(x, mx):
    lo = x.min()
    rng = x.max()-lo
    return (x-lo)*mx/rng

a =np.array([10, 15,16,20, 25, 125, 126, 130, 150, 200, 201., 202])

at = translate(a,255.)
print(at)
# array([  0.      ,   6.640625,   7.96875 ,  13.28125 ,  19.921875,
#        152.734375, 154.0625  , 159.375   , 185.9375  , 252.34375 ,
#        253.671875, 255.      ])
```

The array a stays the same size but the values are stretched to fill the range 0 to 255.

Version 2

```
x = np.arange(len(a)) # An independent x for each a (or at)
new_x = np.linspace( 0., 11., 24)  # Make the result have 25 elements, from 11.
print(new_x)
# [ 0.          0.47826087  0.95652174  1.43478261  1.91304348  2.39130435
#   2.86956522  3.34782609  3.82608696  4.30434783  4.7826087   5.26086957
#   5.73913043  6.2173913   6.69565217  7.17391304  7.65217391  8.13043478
#   8.60869565  9.08695652  9.56521739 10.04347826 10.52173913 11.        ]
```

Use new_x to interpolate the a (or at) values based on x

```
np.interp(new_x, x, at) # The array at is made longer (25 elements) 
# array([  0.        ,   3.17595109,   6.35190217,   7.21807065,
#          7.85326087,  10.04755435,  12.58831522,  15.59103261,
#         18.7669837 ,  60.34307065, 123.86209239, 153.08084239,
#        153.71603261, 155.2173913 , 157.75815217, 163.99456522,
#        176.69836957, 194.59918478, 226.35869565, 252.45923913,
#        253.09442935, 253.72961957, 254.36480978, 255.        ])

np.interp(new_x, x, a) # The original array a is made longer (25 elements) 
# array([ 10.        ,  12.39130435,  14.7826087 ,  15.43478261,
#         15.91304348,  17.56521739,  19.47826087,  21.73913043,
#         24.13043478,  55.43478261, 103.26086957, 125.26086957,
#        125.73913043, 126.86956522, 128.7826087 , 133.47826087,
#        143.04347826, 156.52173913, 180.43478261, 200.08695652,
#        200.56521739, 201.04347826, 201.52173913, 202.        ])
```

I'm not certain either answer meets the question but these are the two ways I can interpret it.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i need to look into interpolation so I would understand exactly what it does